# How can I pass bigger than two digit number to array in calculator jQuery + HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calculator

I'm making a simple calculator using jQuery and HTML. I pass value of buttons to array and convert array to string and calculate total number by using `eval()`.

What I cannot figure it out is to pass value which has more than 2 digit number. Currently I can only pass 1 digit number to array. How can I pass value like 20, 200, 2000 to array?

[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/aaayumi/pen/boaxyg/)

jQuery code :

```
var totalNum = [];

$(".button").click(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("operator")) {
    $("#display").val(($("#display").val()) + ($(this).val()));
    totalNum.push((($("#display").val()) + ($(this).val())));
  } else {
    if ($("#display").val() != '') {
      if ($(this).hasClass("operator")) {
        $("#display").val('');
        totalNum.push(($(this).val()));
      } else {
        $("#display").val(($("#display").val()) + ($(this).val()));
        totalNum.push(($(this).val()));
      }
    }
  }
})

$("#clearButton").click(function() {
  $("#display").val('');
  totalNum = [];
})

$("#equalsButton").click(function() {
  var total = totalNum.join(" ");
  $("#display").val(eval(total));
})
```

Comment: Have you considered what would happen if someone added the text `alert("this application suffers from code injection");` into one of your inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var totalNum = [];

$(".button").click(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("operator")) {
    $("#display").val(($("#display").val()) + ($(this).val()));
    //totalNum.push( (($("#display").val()) ));
    //console.log("two" + totalNum
    console.log('Not operator.');
  } else {
    if ($("#display").val() != '') {
      if ($(this).hasClass("operator")) {
        totalNum.push((($("#display").val())));
        // $("#display").val(($("#display").val()) + ($(this).val()));
        $("#display").val('');
        totalNum.push(($(this).val()));
        console.log("Click operator" + totalNum)
      } else {
        $("#display").val(($("#display").val()) + ($(this).val()));
        totalNum.push(($(this).val()));
        console.log("three" + totalNum)
      }
    }
  }
})

$("#clearButton").click(function() {
  $("#display").val('');
  totalNum = [];
})

$("#equalsButton").click(function() {
  totalNum.push((($("#display").val())));
  var total = totalNum.join(" ");
  console.log("total" + total)
  $("#display").val(eval(total));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input id="display" name="display" disabled></input>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><button id="button1" class="button number" value="1">1</button></td>
    <td><button id="button2" class="button number" value="2">2</button></td>
    <td><button id="button3" class="button number" value="3">3</button></td>
    <td><button id="addButton" class="button operator" value="+">+</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="button4" class="button number" value="4">4</button></td>
    <td><button id="button5" class="button number" value="5">5</button></td>
    <td><button id="button6" class="button number" value="6">6</button></td>
    <td><button id="subtractButton" class="button operator" value="-">-</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="button7" class="button number" value="7">7</button></td>
    <td><button id="button8" class="button number" value="8">8</button></td>
    <td><button id="button9" class="button number" value="9">9</button></td>
    <td><button id="multiplyButton" class="button operator" value="*">*</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="clearButton">C</button></td>
    <td><button id="button0" class="button number" value="0">0</button></td>
    <td><button id="equalsButton">=</button></td>
    <td><button id="divideButton" class="button operator" value="/">&#247;</button></td>
  </tr>



</table>
```

It's my solution and it's not only answer.

It's just a way to solve your problem.

If I make a calculator, I will try to make plan.

When user clicked `number button`, I don't `push()`.

When user clicked `operator button`, I do `push()` before when I inputted number.

And I also do `push()` the `operator sign`.

When user clicked `equal button`, I do `push()` before when I inputted number and I do `eval()` and display the result of calculate.

I hope.. understand my explain.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! Your solution is much simpler than I though of. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: @aaayumi It's my pleasure :)